# How to refresh kendo grid data when i sort or click on column?

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a grid below when user click on subcategory Name column i am populating another grid on right side that is data for selected row, I want to add function to subcategory Name column when user click i want to refresh right side grid data to default. (no data should be display in right side until user select a row).

```
angular.module('thirdPartyManagementApp').value('subCategoryGridConfig', {
subCategoryGrid: {
    sortable: true,
    filterable: true,
    selectable: true,
    height: 600,
    toolbar: [
        {
            template: kendo.template('<kendo-tabstrip><ul><li ng-class="{\'k-state-hover k-state-active\': defaultAllTab}"><a  href="" class="k-grid-add border"  ng-click="getAllSubCategories()">All</a></li>')
        },
        {
            template: kendo.template('<li ng-class="{\'k-state-hover k-state-active\': defaultPendingTab}"><a  href="" class="k-grid-add border" ng-click="getPendingSubCategories()">Pending Review</a></li>')
        },
        {
            template: kendo.template('<li ng-class="{\'k-state-hover k-state-active\': defaultReviewTab}"><a  href="" class="k-grid-add border" ng-click="getReviewedSubCategories()">Reviewed</a></li></ul><kendo-tabstrip>')
        }
    ],
    columns: [
        {
            template: '<strong><span ng-if="this.dataItem.sortCode === 1" class="text-success">NEW</span><span ng-if="this.dataItem.sortCode === 2" class="text-danger">!</span></strong>',
            width: '30px'
        },
        {                           
            template: kendo.template('{{this.dataItem.subCategoryName}}<br/><a  href="" class="linkColor hoverFontColor" ng-click="showDetail(this.dataItem)">Vendors...</a>'),
            field: 'subCategoryName',
            title: 'Subcategory',
            width: '100px',
            template: (function(e) {
              subCategoryGrid.columns.filter(function(data) {
                return data.field === "subCategoryName";
              })
              subCategoryGrid.refresh();
            });
        },
        {
            field: 'status',
            title: 'Status',
            width: '65px'
        }
    ]
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kendo grid hasn't sorting event, but datasource contains `change` event that fires when data changed and also sorted:

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#events-change

Try update data in this event handler

Don't forget check e.action to prevent loop

Comment: The Kendo Grid does have a sorting event